# Why are the tableView methods named as they are?

Tags: ios, swift

Unless I've misunderstood the language (I've just started learning swift), whats the reason for naming all of the methods the same and using the (external) parameter to identify it? Which I assume could be convention for protocols/delegates.

The only reason I can think of is making the code easier to read, but even so it just doesn't feel right when I look at it.

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int // Default is 1 if not implemented
```

(The last one looks normal/how I'd expect it to be)

Comment: As @sschale said, it's historical and comes from Objective-C. It actually makes a lot of sense with the Objective-C syntax: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Comment: They are not in any sense "all the same".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, it is partly historical and makes a lot of sense in Objective-C where the actual method name of

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is

```
- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

With swift, the language designers opted to use named parameters to keep the readability of functions in the code that made Objective-C code easy to understand.

Also, named parameters are a safety feature: You are much less likely to switch function parameters (especially of the same type) if they are named and their names make their purpose obvious.

With that in mind, duplicating the named parameters in the function name seems unneccessary and the framework's functions beeing massively bridged from Objective-C at this time stay similar to their Obj-C versions.

This would otherwise (this is the historical part) be hard for existing developers, forcing a new naming scheme on them and might keep them from using swift.